# Disable Spring @Autowired Provider<T> behaviour

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a bean of type `Provider<Foo>` in my Spring context.  I'd like to `@Autowire` that bean into another class.

```
@Autowired
private Provider<Foo> fooProvider;
```

However, Spring looks at this and decides that I must've defined a bean of type `Foo` in my context, and that I want that wrapped that in a `Provider` so that Spring can manage its scope.

That's not what I want; I don't have a `Foo`, I have a `Provider<Foo>`.  Spring complains:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: **No matching bean of type [my.package.Foo] found for dependency**: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

How can I ask Spring to be less clever and just autowire the type I want?

### Update

Thanks for the questions.  I created a test case to illustrate my problem:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:foo-context.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class
})
public class FooProviderTest {

    @Autowired
    private javax.inject.Provider<Foo> fooProvider;

    @Test
    public void verifyFooProviderAutowired() {
        assertEquals("foo", fooProvider.get().getFooName());
    }
}

class Foo {
    public String getFooName() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

class SimpleFooProvider implements javax.inject.Provider<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo get() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}
```

The foo-context.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        ">
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="fooProvider" class="example.SimpleFooProvider"/>
</beans>
```

The output of the test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [example.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectFactory.getObject(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyProvider.get(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at example.FooProviderTest.verifyFooProviderAutowired(FooProviderTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Note that the test does not fail on the assertion; it fails to initialise the application context.

Curiously, explicitly changing the test field's declared type from `Provider<Foo>` to `SimpleFooProvider`  results in the test passing with no complaint.  That is,

```
@Autowired
private SimpleFooProvider fooProvider;
```

Comment: Does your Provider extend from a `Map` type or a `List` type, if so that could be what is triggering this behavior from Spring.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen I believe it's `javax.inject.Provider`.

Comment: Can you show us your declaration of the `Provider` bean in the context? I'd also like to see more of the exception stack trace? Do you get it on init or when you try to use the `fooProvider`?

Comment: Yes, you are right @SotiriosDelimanolis. Very neat.

Comment: Thanks for the questions guys.  I've updated my question to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Provider` is `javax.inject.Provider`, Spring will very much autowire a `Provider` implementation into this field

```
@Autowired
private Provider<Foo> fooProvider;
```

For example, this is done through the following call hierarchy

```
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#inject(Object bean, String beanName, PropertyValues pvs)
DefaultListableBeanFactory#resolveDependency(DependencyDescriptor descriptor, String beanName,Set<String> autowiredBeanNames, TypeConverter typeConverter)
DependencyProviderFactory#createDependencyProvider(DependencyDescriptor descriptor, String beanName)
```

which creates a `DependencyProvider` object which is implemented as

```
private class DependencyProvider extends DependencyObjectFactory implements Provider<Object> {

    public DependencyProvider(DependencyDescriptor descriptor, String beanName) {
        super(descriptor, beanName);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get() throws BeansException {
        return getObject();
    }
}
```

where `getObject()` fetches the bean from the enclosing `DefaultListableBeanFactory` instance.

So, if anything, you are probably getting your exception when trying to call

```
fooProvider.get();
```

because that tries to get a `Foo` bean from the context and doesn't find one.

Comment: This is true, but it won't autowire the _right_ `Provider` into this field.  Or at least, it won't autowire the `Provider` I want.  :)  I'm interested in whether or not there's a way to configure Spring not to choose to autowire its own `DependencyProvider` but instead use the one I've already declared in the context.

Comment: @Samwise I'd have to re-read the CDI specification, but I don't think it should. I think it's the IoC container's job to provide a `Provider`.

Comment: @Samwise As far as I can tell, there isn't.

Comment: Fair enough.  From digging into the code, it looks like `DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency()` explicitly checks to see if the declared type is of `javax.inject.Provider`, and if so, uses its own `DependencyProvider`.  I have a viable workaround (declaring the type as my sub-interface or its impl), or perhaps I'll cease using `Provider` to avoid stepping on the IoC container's toes.

Comment: `@Autowired`
`private Provider<Foo> fooProvider;`
Here if there are multiple named beans which return type `Foo`, how do I make the provider return a particular named bean?

Comment: @nishant I'm sorry, I've been away from Spring too long. Consider asking a new question.